# Cannot read property 'getDate'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, keystonejs

I'm using keystone for my project. In 'Post' database there is publishedDate and I want to format it with code under.

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var monthNames = [
        "Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart",
        "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz",
        "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim",
        "Kasım", "Aralık"
    ];

    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    return day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
}


var q = keystone.list('Post').model.findOne({
        state: 'published',
        slug: locals.filters.post,
    }).populate('author categories');

    q.exec(function (err, result) {
        Object.keys(result).forEach(function (key) {
            var element = result[key];              
            element.newDate = formatDate(element.publishedDate);
        });

        locals.data.post = result;
        next(err);
    });

});
```

When I run project an error occurs. But I know 'publishedDate' is a Date value.

```
 Mongoose model 'error' event fired on 'Post' with error:
 Cannot read property 'getDate' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDate' of undefined
```

Comment: `element.newDate = formatDate(new Date(element.publishedDate));`. you're passing a string to a function that expects a Date Object

Comment: It appears that  `element.publishedDate` is not set.

Comment: it says `property 'getDate' of undefined`, so you should try to find out why it is `undefined`

Comment: Just check if **element** has `publish edDate` property or not. If it doesn't have, it will be `undefined` and you will get error as you're getting.

Comment: The whole `Object.keys(result).forEach` thing is suspect. You've done `findOne`. Would it really return an object where each and every property refers to an object with a `publishedDate` property? That seems odd. I'd expect you to be doing a `find` and getting an array.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. I removed object loop and just wrote "result.newDate = formatDate(result.publishedDate);" then it worked

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
var day = date.getDate();
var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();
```

Into

```
var day = new Date(date).getDate();
var monthIndex = new Date(date).getMonth();
var year = new Date(date).getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

From you code:

```
var day = date.getDate();
var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();
```

are you sure in the `date` object you really have a `getDate()`, `date.getMonth()`, `getFullYear()` because I haven't seen where you instantiated your date `new Date()`.

Maybe you might want to go through this, it might help.

```js
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDate();
    var month = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    
    if(day<10) {
        day = `0${day}`
    } 
    
    if(month<10) {
        month = `0${month}`
    } 
    
    today = `${month} / ${day} / ${year}`;
    alert(`Today's date is "${today}"`);
```